# Div Card Elements Won't Scroll

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and am creating a website for a basic university course. For a project, I have created 8 div cards highlighting the planets of the Solar System but cannot get the cards out of this fixed/unscrollable position.
This is the link to the current page state:

https://hollandtheperson.com/dight/250/website/planets.html

Any tips on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have added `overflow: hidden;` for the CSS in the body tag, which hides the scrollbar essentially making the scroll feature unusable, if you remove it then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `overflow-x` instead of `overflow` to hidden, like so:

```css
...
overflow-x: hidden;
...
```

This disables horizontal scroll but allows vertical scroll

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't really with it being fixed in place, but i can see why you got that impression.

You're using `overflow: hidden;` which means "if something doesn't fit, snip it off".

So, because the overflow has cut away everything wasn't already within the viewport - there is now nothing outside the viewport, and hence, no reason to allow scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the **.card** height and add **overflow-x: hidden** which give you scrolling card. Sample code given below:

```
.card{
// add additional code
height: 350px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can see that you have added items in css of body tags which i guess you should remove in order make it scrollable feature those are

```
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
```

Please check if that works hopefully it should be.